# Divide 2-dimensional array into not equal rectangles and squares

Tags: java, arrays, math

I need to divide 2d array into chunks like in this image (I can't post images yet)

[image]

If main diagonal =1. Then I check next square. If I have rectangle I check only points (0,0) and (1,1).
Array can be divided into squares of 4*4, 3*3,2*2.
I think it must be like this

```
for (int i=start;i<start+len_of_square;i++)
    for (int j=start;j<start+len_of_square;j++)
        {
            //do checking
        }
```

But it will work only if array can be divided into equal squares.
Are there some algorithms to do this?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Do you need a formula for the same?

Comment: I need algorithm to do the same like in picture and divide also this array on 3*3 and 2*2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the rules and regulations in stack overflow. Check the following algorithm matches your requirement. instead of loop through all cells and eliminating one by one using "if" use the following way. It will be much faster since loop will run length of full array/division times only

```
for(int i=0;i<length of full array/division  && i<length of full array;i++)
{
      for(int j=0;j<length of full array/division && j<length of full array;j++)
      {
           //do operation for array[divison*i][division*j] and  array[divison*i+1][division*j+1]
      }
}
```

it will check if division is 4  as per picture then (0,0),(1,1),(0,4),(1,5),(0,8),(1,9),(4,0)(5,1).... order

Comment: If you don't know much about the rules and regulations, then that's the first thing you need to learn. You should complete the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) - you earn a badge for that - and you should go through the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). If you don't, you're sure to earn a lot of downvotes before long.